# New language doesn't show up in the menu

Tags: magento2, language, language-package

I have a **german/english** store.

I wanted to add the `dutch language` for `Netherlands`.

I installed it with composer from this [site](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack)

Then I changed the language in the store config as following : 
[image]

But it doesnt show up in my **language menu** which still show only `English` and `German`:
[image]

But I can see the changed in the admin login page :
[image]

Am I missing something ???

Comment: How many stores and store views you have created?

Comment: check my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Magento 2 multiple Languages**

You should create for these following steps:

1. Create store
2. Create store view
3. Create Language

[image]

> php bin/magento cache:flush

For more, check youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C56jJpZuSw)

Comment: Happy to help dear! @IsmailBerlin